# Only render to partial blocks with express and jade

Tags: html, node.js, web, express, pug

I was wondering if its possible to render the layout of an express application once using node.js and express.  I want to have a stream playing on the layout page but I fear it will stop every time i want to render to the blocks I've declared.

Comment: You can use Ajax for that (if you don't want to reload page and if I understood your question :) )

Comment: jQuery is nice library for javascript and it has nice mthods for ajax too, see this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ajax example:

```
$.get('url', function(response){
    $('#divToUpdateId').html(response);
});
```

Or this is the same:

```
$('#divToUpdateId').load('url');
```